# FPDF: How to send JSON data to FPDF to generate PDF document in php

Tags: php, json, fpdf

I have installed FPDF in my project, and want to generate a PDF file that contains data in a table format. I want to send JSON formatted data to FPDF. How to do this?

My JSON data is this:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "ttfdgdf": "Input1"
},
{
  "number": "12"
},
{
  "gfgfgrg": "Sagar"
},
{
  "bfghngfh": "12323445"
},
{
  "mvbmnbm": "Hi this is sagar coming from satara\t\t\t\t"
},
{
  "1425278796425303": "on"
},
{
  "1425278796425605": "on"
},
{
  "lkl": "Hiiii"
},
{
  "lklkl": "1:12 AM"
}
]
}
```

Comment: i tried my level best to find it out on google but i did not get any relevant posts matching to requirement for json specifically...

Comment: Take it a step at a time. Can you echo the JSON in your PHP file successfully? If so, then you have everything you need to use that data in FPDF, assuming you know how FPDF works.